# Построение графика с помощью jquery.flot.js

Tags: jquery, javascript

Приложение на Javascript c использованием библиотек jquery.js и jquery.flot.js выполняется во всех браузерах кроме Internet Explorer, выдает такое сообщение об ошибке-:

> `Unable to get value of the property 'initElement': object is null or undefined`

редактор высветил как ошибочную следующую строку

```
canvas = window.G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
```

Где искать решение проблемы?

Comment: мож window обернуть в $(window) ? oO

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer и canvas? это фантастика. а вообще есть js библиотечка для реализации всех возвожностей canvas в осликах http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Answer (score 0):

там библиотека у них есть канвас. качаешь и подключаешь

```
<!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```